# Java remote interface blocks the use of my GUI

Tags: java, javafx, interface, rmi, observable

I've given a bank application which I should modify so the balance of an account gets updated on every GUI screen. This should be done with RMI(Observable) in my example. I already made this work, at least, I'm almost certain about that.

There is a REMOTE interface called `IBankingSession`.
This REMOTE interface should have a method like `setGUI(BankSessionController)` or something like this. But, This isn't possible because the JavaFX parts aren't `Serializable`. The `IBankingSession` doesn't have any relationship to a GUI. 
How can I link an instance of `IBankingSession` to this GUI? So I can update the GUI from this instance? It also feels weird to make a method like `setGUI` in a REMOTE interface. Because the GUI is of course, on the same screen as where the session is created.

I'm curious for some good idea's. Thanks in advance.

```
IBankingSession session = desk.logIn(tfAccount.getText(), tfPassword.getText());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: you don't want to link your "remote" thing directly to your local clients that make use of it. That IBankingSession has no business knowing anything about the fact that your client wants to use JavaFx to put something on the user screens.

Instead, try something like this: define an interface that allows for callbacks (in other words: some kind of "push" model):

A client registers with the remote server; telling it: "I am interested in balance updates".

Then, upon a "balance" update, the remote service pushes that information to each client.

Now each client will be notified; and can then decide what to do with incoming updates; for example update some JavaFx UI component; or maybe, to log them into some persistent storage - giving you one mechanism that might be useful for a huge variety of different use cases.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using observables at all, and certainly not over a network.

As far as RMI goes, you should strenously avoid anything in the nature of a client-side callback. There are firewall problems, latency problems, connectivity problems, ... every kind of thing that could cause your client to misfire.

You need to completely rethink this. It is not a viable design.